# MVC Edit method resets field to default value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, default-value

I have a Customer Model containing the following properties:
Id, Name and AccountBalance.

A Customer can register an account, but is not able to specify his AccountBalance (I didn't include it in the create method parameter

```
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Id,Name")] Customer customer)
```

I added a HiddenFor in the View method:

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AccountBalance)
```

This all works fine, the customer can create an account and the accountbalance defaults to 0.

The problem occurs when editing the customer's account. I don't want the customer to be able to edit his accountbalance, so I also omitted it from the edit method and added a hiddenfor in the edit method's view. When I edit a customer's name for instance, the AccountBalance resets to 0.

How do I deny the user from changing the AccountBalance, but have MVC not reset the value to 0?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not much point including a hidden input if your excluding it from binding but either 1) Include hidden input and remove the `BindAttribute` or 2) Fetch the customer again from the repository on post back and update only the properties you want to.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing number 2 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving it with Stephen Meucke's suggestion:

```
    var original = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == customer.Id);
    customer.AccountBalance= original.AccountBalance;

    db.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(customer);

    db.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't say thank you by using his answer but not giving him an upvote for his help. That's not cool.

Comment: If you look closely, you'll see that his answer was a COMMENT on my question, which I did upvote.

Answer (score 1):

**Stephen Muecke**'s first suggestion works for me. Didn't try the second one yet.

On your ***Controller***:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="Id,Name,AccountBalance")] Customer customer)
```

Then on your ***View***:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AccountBalance)
```

Hope this helps and works for others! :)